# Angular4 + Bootstrap 4 Footer at bootom of page

Tags: css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, footer

already searched google and this board and tried a lot of the solutions is found but without any success. I like to have a `footer` at the bottom of any site (and if the site is not high enough at the bottom of the viewport).

I'm using Angular4 and Bootstrap4 and this is my current code (this is one template, need to devide it because SO has problems with it):

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z2" *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn()">
<button mat-button class="pull-left" [disabled]="!auth.isLoggedIn()" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
    <i class="fa fa-navicon" aria-hidden="true"></i> PowerPals
</button>

<div *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn()">
    <button mat-button class="pull-left" (click)="showProfile()">
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="d-none d-sm-inline"> {{auth.username$ | async}}</span>
    </button>

    <button id="logoutButton" mat-button class="pull-right" (click)="logout()">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="d-none d-sm-inline"> ABMELDEN</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

```
<mat-sidenav-container (window:resize)="onResize($event)" [style]="mainStyle.getValue()">
<mat-sidenav *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn()" [mode]="sidenavMode" [opened]="true" #sidenav class="sidenav-shadow">
    <app-nav-pane *ngFor="let nav of (app.navmods$ | async)" [content]="nav"></app-nav-pane>
</mat-sidenav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" style="flex: 1 0 auto;">
        <div class="col-12">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
        Footer
    </div>
</footer>
```

I want to footer to be, as said before, at the end of every page or the viewport. At the moment it's looking like this:

[image]

But the footer should be at the bottom of the page. Does anyone have a solution with this? I currently don't use any special `css` because no of the solutions i found worked.

Any help would be great :-)

Comment: In my solution I set two classes to footer like this: `<footer class="card-footer fixed-bottom"`>bla bla</footer>` but I'm using bootstrap 4 there are few examples on this link https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/ Cheers

Comment: `fixed-bottom` was the thing I'm missing. If you make this an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Find some more problems. It's still not in the `sidenav` (if I close or open it, it won't move) - even if it's in the tag

Comment: In my case the `footer` is not hidden, maybe is not a suitable solution for you, but I will share it too. I just add the `footer` after `</mat-sidenav-container>` tag.  Also Try to add your footer with this sidenav example on StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/angular/pxgdyeqoojon?file=app%2Fsidenav-open-close-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `card-footer` and `fixed-bottom` css classes (see: [bootstrap v4 fixed-bottom](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#fixed-bottom)), like this.

```
<footer class="card-footer fixed-bottom"><div>bla bla</div></footer>
```

Just make sure that footer is after `</mat-sidenav-container>`

*Note*: this solution will keep footer visible even if sidenav is hidden because it is added just after sidenav-container close tag.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer by Daniel C.

You can use the footer with out the card also.

For example:

```
<footer class="fixed-bottom"><div>my footer</div></footer>
```